# Adding button to icon tab bar

Tags: sapui5

[image: The layout]
I am designing a basic layout. I want to add a button in the same row as my icon tab bar. I can find any solution to it.Posted a picture above for reference.

```
<mvc:View controllerName="Workspace.test01.controller.App" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
<Page title="{i18n>homePageTitle}">
    <content>
        <IconTabBar id="idIconTabBarNoIcons" class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding">
            <items>
                <IconTabFilter text="abc" class="Tabheader">
                </IconTabFilter>
                <IconTabFilter text="fdvvvfv"></IconTabFilter>
                <IconTabFilter text="vdfvvdvvv"></IconTabFilter>
                <IconTabFilter text="Avfdsd"></IconTabFilter>
            </items>
        </IconTabBar>
    </content>
</Page>
```

Comment: What is the problem you're running into?

Comment: I want to use the icon tab bars and on the right  hand side i want to show a button

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve it using `HBox` and `layoutData`

```
<l:VerticalLayout width="100%" >
    <HBox>
        <IconTabBar>
            <items>
                <IconTabFilter text="abc" class="Tabheader">
                </IconTabFilter>
                <IconTabFilter text="fdvvvfv"></IconTabFilter>
                <IconTabFilter text="vdfvvdvvv"></IconTabFilter>
                <IconTabFilter text="Avfdsd"></IconTabFilter>
            </items>
            <layoutData>
                <FlexItemData growFactor="2" />
            </layoutData>
        </IconTabBar>
        <Button text="Button" class="sapUiSmallMarginTop sapUiTinyMarginBegin" />
    </HBox>
</l:VerticalLayout>
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add the  aggregation with the button but then it gets rendered below the IconTabBar. I guess your best bet is to extend the IconTabBar and create a custom control that accepts a button in the  aggregation.